# How to even open a web page from local server with IE?? got me crazy

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a django app running in my local server on this PC. It works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera but in IE it loads the html but after 10min is still loading some content. The content shown is without css (only background color is shown) and without javscript. I can't even debug a simple page with IE because in order to load it takes long LONGGGG TIMEEE! I have to close open multiple times.

ps: genuine windows and IE!
How can even exist an app like IE  in 2011?
(internet explorer help doesn't work because it's vista and can't read help files)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is because the app is deployed on a local machine? Maybe you just have problem with your code in IE.

Comment: it's always loading something. but what I don't know.. it's always unfinished... What might be a problem for only IE don't load all files?